# Get Raster Values from a Polygon Overlay in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, polygon

I have the same problem as Curlew in [Get Raster Values from a Polygon Overlay in Opensource GIS Solutions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23614/get-raster-values-from-a-polygon-overlay-in-opensource-gis-solutions) and thecrashlandingdodo in [Step-by-step: How do I extract Raster values from Polygon overlay with Q-GIS or R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102870/step-by-step-how-do-i-extract-raster-values-from-polygon-overlay-with-q-gis-or). Curlew says it's rather easily done in ArcGIS, but I just don't know how and R is on my to-learn list.

I have many polygons in a shapefile and a raster with different values. I would like to know for each polygon how many percent each raster value has in that polygon. Any of the zonal stats does not seem to do this (or did I miss something?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS, you can use [tabulate area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w2000000.htm) for this. It will give you a table as output with the number of pixels of each class within each polygon. Then you need to divide each column by a the total count and you have the percent. Note that ArcGIS selects a default raster size for internal analysis. So it is better to specify the pixel size in the environment of the tool (otherwise, you could have resampling errors).

From QGIS, [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/is-there-a-tabulate-area-function-in-qgis) indicates that SAGA GIS has the tool